# Finding linear functionals on $\mathbb R^4$ the intersection of whose null spaces is a linear span.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find two linear functionals in  $\mathbb R^4$ the intersection of whose null spaces is the linear span of $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(1,0,-1,0)$. You now have in hand a linear transformation whose null space is the above span. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two linear transformations with null space being as you asked. Here are two ones.

$$T(x,y,v,w)=x+v-y-w$$ and 
$$S(x,y,v,w)=x+v-3y+w$$.

Comment: Please check your calculations noticing the difference between $v$ and $y$.

Comment: Now, my mistake!!! Thanks for your attention. I made the required changes.